# powershell get changed files and copy them

Tags: filesystems, powershell

Trying to copy all changed files from a directory (recursively) to a new location, keeping the directory structure intact.

I put the changed files into an array:
$datechanged = ($datechanged).addyears(-3)
$changedfiles = ls -recurse | where-object{$_.lastwritetime -gt $datechanged}

Now I would like to copy these files (and directories?) to a new location, but am not sure how to proceed.

I have been trying the syntax of foreach, but I am not having much luck. I am doing this as a learning exercise, but with an actual goal in mind of archiving these changed files - so putting the files directly into a 7-zip file would be great for speed, but I would like to better understand how to deal with these arrays of objects and pipeline them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reinventing the wheel here. [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx) will do exactly what you want.

Edit: on the off chance that you are already aware of robocopy, I found powershell.com's [Mastering PowerShell](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/) ebook quite a good starting point for getting to grips with PowerShell.